# word-wrap:break-word not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, word-wrap

Can anyone please tell me why `word-wrap: break-word` will not work in IE8?

I have this working in other browsers but IE8 refuses to listen despite reading this post on their site?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531186(VS.85).aspx

Thanks

Comment: It says, right at the top of the page you linked to 'CSS     { -ms-word-wrap : sWrap } '  Why are you expecting the unprefixed version to work?

Comment: @robertc: I think the non-prefixed versions generally still work in IE 8? If they didn’t, a bunch of sites would have broken in IE 8.

Comment: @PaulDWaite I thought this was one of those things that was unprefixed in the beta and ended up prefixed in the release?

Comment: I tried the prefixed and none prefixed version. And in their examples, it's actually not prefixed either.

Comment: Thanks guys, I came right in the end

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `word-wrap: break-word;` is indeed supported in Internet Explorer 8, but the styled element must [have layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Comment: Yes. The page the OP linked says it right there: `This property applies to elements that have layout. An element has layout when it is absolutely positioned, is a block element, or is an inline element with a specified height or width.`

Comment: Adding `display: inline-block;` to an element fixed an issue where `word-wrap:break-word;` would not trigger on IE8. Giving it a layout with `display: inline-block; solved this and works fine in all browsers. Highly important to have layout. Great link to read through in answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

I found that to apply `word-wrap` to a `td` (table cell) I needed to style the `table` element with `table-layout: fixed`. (IE8 standards mode.)

Comment: this is also needed for chrome

Comment: thank you so much! I needed this to use word-wrap in a table cell for the orbeon renderer.

Comment: just using  of `table-layout: fixed` is not enough. you need also use of `width`

Comment: That's great, it maintains the integrity of the th witdhs. It works IE7+, Chrome, Mozilla, Safari. Can do something like the following, just give the table tag a class of "table-wrap":
.table-wrap {table-layout: fixed;}
.table-wrap tr td{word-wrap:break-word;}

Answer (score 12):

Try this 
**word-break: break-all;** , for IE8 and IE9 it is working :)

Comment: Easy and effective...!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "word-break" and "word-wrap" are two different things. 

In the following example, "word-break: break-all;" would cut the word
"consectetuer" in half and "word-wrap: break-word" does not. 

    <div style="width: 222px; font: 14px sans-serif;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>

Comment: This really isn't the same thing. Break-all will break words in the middle even if it is not necessary. Break-word will only break a word if it will not fit on a line on its own.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: Please add some additional explanation to your answer.

Comment: MDN clearly states:

> IE8 introduced -ms-word-break as a synonym for word-break. Don't use the -ms- prefix.

Answer (score -1):

After looking at this example code from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531186%28VS.85%29.aspx

I managed to fix my issues with IE-8 with the following addition to the 
document and header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

...and then use this (official) CSS directive:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Seems very heavy handed. I don't think I'd recommend to anyone to make an app render with IE7's terrible rendering engine just for a word-break. Especially since this will make IE9 and up render as IE7.

Comment: Unfair to vote this one down! At least it did work for me. A bad solution but a solution still.