# word wrap on html paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph tag inside a table, and for example it has a text like this...

```
4: asldkflaksdjflks, lasjdlfjsaldfjasldjfoajsdkfjaslkdjlkfasjdfwoidjfalk,zmncv,mznoqeworjoiejflaksdlfjwaf
```

How can the text wrap something like this..

```
4: asldkflaksdjflks, lasjdlfjsaldfjasldjfoajsdkfjaslkdjlkfasj
dfwoidjfalk,zmncv,mznoqeworjoiejflaksdlfjwaf
```

I have tried `word-wrap:break-word;` but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using IE8

Here is my css:

```
#notes table tr td p{
    font-family:Arial;
    padding:2% 2% 2% 5%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

## Update 1

I was wrong with my question. Sorry about that. I want the text not to wrap, even though there is a white-space. But it will go down to the next line if necessary. Hope that I'm clearer this time.

Is there a character that looks like a space, but doesn't serve as a breakpoint for the word wrap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to word wrap text in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

Comment: `word-wrap:break-word` will only break the word if it is necessary; it gives it permission to break a word, but doesn't force it to. If normal word wrapping can be displayed without any overflows, then it'll use that in preference to breaking the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is an HTML non-breaking space. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could put your text into a `<pre>` tag, and put the `<pre>` tag in you `<p>` tag.
A `<pre>` allows you to control text wrapping within the html. If the `<p>` collapses to the size of the `<pre>`, then set a width on the `<p>`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here : http://www.css3files.com/text/#wordwrap the word-wrap property is not compatible with IE8.

I think it's impossible to do this on IE8 with simple HTML and CSS, you will have to do it in javascript.

EDIT: It seems that there's finally a solution for that : [word-wrap:break-word not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997223/word-wrapbreak-word-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in jquery..but so far not luck