# CSS word-wrap: break-word don't work on IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, word-wrap

I have a small css script that force `<a>` tag word-wrap in a div. It worked fine on FF, Chrome but didn't work on IE9. How can I fix it?

```
.tab_title a{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: The solution in this post worked for me: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042412/2383765](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042412/2383765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remove the anchor tag after `.tab_title` class and it works

Comment: .tab_title{        
        word-wrap: break-word;   
    }
    .tab_title a{
            word-break: break-word;
    }

Answer (score 29):

For a similar issue, I used `display: inline-block` on the `<a>` tag, which seems to help. And `word-break: break-all` as I was concerned with long URLs not wrapping.

So, this in your case essentially...

```
.tab_title a {
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For me it worked in both Chrome and IE with:

```css
.word-hyphen-break {
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
}
```

like this no need to configure specific width.

Answer (score 13):

This might do the trick:
http://www.last-child.com/word-wrapping-for-internet-explorer/

Another post also suggests applying `word-break:break-all` and `word-wrap:break-word` to it.

Comment: like this link suggested "word-break: break-all" does the job! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
.tab_title a{
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: That approach does not work with display flex, I changed the element to display block and worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`word-wrap: word-break;` works only in ff and chrome and not in IE8 and IE9.
`word-break: break-all;`  does not work either.

Answer (score 3):

I have had good success in Chrome, Firefox and IE with using:

```
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

In my problem case I was using:

```
display: table-cell;
```

and I ended up having to include

```
max-width: 440px;
```

to get wrapping in all browsers.  In most cases the max-width was not necessary.  Using

```
word-break: break-all;
```

does not work well in IE because although long words without spaces will be wrapped, short words also stop wrapping at spaces.

Comment: fyi, I also had the same issue with IE11.  I got it to wrap big words in my table, but it seems to wrap tiny words as well, when it could have easily put it into a separate line.  I'm glad I'm not the only one.  Did using max-width fix it for you?  I just tried it on my TD, but no luck.

Comment: Yes, in most cases: word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; worked, but in the one case that it didn't, also specifying max-width did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was fighting this in Angular between IE/Edge & Chrome.  Here is what I found worked for me

```
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
```

This gave me the best of both.  It would break the word that was too long, but unlike word-break it would not break mid-word.

Answer (score -1):

i just figured out that word-wrap:break-word works only partially in IE8 and IE9. If I have a string of words with spaces, then that string gets wrapped. But if my string consists of one long word, it forces the parent/container element to expand according to its width