# word-wrap:break-word css property not working on IE8 standard mode

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

CSS property word-wrap:break-word is not working on IE8 standard mode but same is working on IE 7 and other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<div style="width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;">
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997223/word-wrapbreak-word-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
```