# word-break css not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, word-wrap

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997223/word-wrapbreak-word-not-working-in-ie8) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583793/word-wrapbreak-word-css-property-not-working-on-ie8-standard-mode), and tried both methods to apply word breaking to a span tag. Neither one works in IE8 for me.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
.bodyWrap .dashboard .col2 .wrapper .locInfoWrap .nickname { 
    font-size:16px;  
    color:#000;  
    word-wrap:break-word;  
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word; 
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
}
```

**EDITED TO ADD** - I just tried adding a width to the span element, like this:

```
.bodyWrap .dashboard .col2 .wrapper .locInfoWrap .nickname { 
        font-size:16px;  
        color:#000;  
        word-wrap:break-word;  
        -ms-word-wrap: break-word; 
        -ms-word-break: break-all;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Still looks the same. Help, please! This is a major requirement for our client.

Here's what it ends up looking like (larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hookedbyesther/10443155253/)):
[image]

What do I need to do to get this to work in IE8?

Comment: you tried setting a width to that span?

Comment: @razhial - my understanding was that using the ms-specific properties would make it work on elements that don't have layout. The documentation for [-ms-word-wrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that layout is required; [-ms-word-break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Wouldn't trust them. ;)
No, im sorry, i can't help you then.

Comment: make that `span` to a block element

Comment: The solution in this post worked for me: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042412/2383765](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042412/2383765)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ended up working for me was setting the span to have a display of `inline-block`.

Comment: thanks a lot, you helped me ! I spent like 2 hours looking for a solution for quite a similar problem and adding display:inline-block fixed it !