# How to wrap text in a <a> element in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

As `<a>` elements often contain long URLs with various tokens, this often breaks out of the outer container the link is in.

To prevent this, there are the CSS properties `word-wrap`, `word-break` and `-ms-word-break`(for earlier versions of IE). However, I couldn't get those working in IE (tried with IE11).

Here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t54UJ/2/).

How can I make content of a `<a>` element automatically wrap inside of it's outer container in IE11?

Comment: You should first ask the questions “Should I really have URLs as web page content?” (rather than in attributes) and “If I should, what are the permissible line break points within a URL?”. The question as currently asked seems to imply that any break is OK, but this is not true.

Comment: As users can freely decide what they put in as <a>-content, I cannot change this. Also, I would feel that any break point within a URL is okay. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: You can filter out content, or otherwise process it. And all the relevant authorities, such as the IETF (STD 66) and The Chicago Manual of Style, say that URLs must not be broken arbitrarily (though they may have different views on acceptable break points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link should have following styles to wrap properly:

```css
a {
    word-wrap:wrap-word;
    word-break:break-all;
    display:inline-block; /* block would also work */
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. Does using `display:inline-block` have any downsides?

Comment: It has only limited support below IE8 which should not be of any relevance [see here](http://caniuse.com/inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually getting interesting.

First, I asked myself: "Could it be a [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) issue?" *(An old related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997257/1725764))*

Hence I made a **[test on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UhiGANil/3/edit)**, and checked the result on **IE8** (Windows7).

But I faced an strange behavior.

In that Demo, `word-wrap: break-word;` doesn't work properly on an `inline` element such as `<a>` tag. But if you set that on the parent (`<div>` element) it works!

While the [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that this property will be applied to *all elements*.

Once you change `display` property of that inline element to `block` it would work without error.

On the other hand, There's a same situation for using `word-break: break-all;` on an `inline` element; it won't work.

But when we change the `display` property of the element to `inline-block` or `block`, it works well.

I don't exactly know why this happens. (In my knowledge) The spec doesn't stated anything about this.

But if those two CSS declarations are set on the container, they'll work on different web browsers (IE as well):

```css
div {  /* <-- the container */
  word-wrap:break-word;
  word-break:break-all;
  /* other styles... */
}
```

Comment: As this should only be applied to links (other text in the container must be wrapped normally), I cannot set it on the container. Quite interesting that MSDN states that it is applied on all elements when it obviously is not. Are there any downsides of using `display:inline-block`?

Comment: Not at all, If you don't care about IE 6/7 :)

Comment: @Zulakis I should improve my comment: By default, IE5.5-7 only supports [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility) on naturally *inline* elements. In this case it would work properly.